# Encode two double quotation marks in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following string saved in database:

```
<p>ampersand (&amp;), bracket(&lt;&gt;), quotation marks (&quot;&quot;&#39;&#39;)</p>\r\n
```

I need to encode the special symbols and get a string

```
<p>ampersand (&), bracket(<>), quotation marks (""'')</p>
```

I used CGI library to encoding:

```
CGI::unescapeHTML("<p>ampersand (&amp;), bracket(&lt;&gt;), quotation marks (&quot;&quot;&#39;&#39;)</p>\r\n")
```

the method returns `"<p>ampersand (&), bracket(<>), quotation marks (\"\"'')</p>\r\n"`

but should be

```
<p>ampersand (&), bracket(<>), quotation marks (""'')</p>
```

Comment: You're confusing the contents of the string with its representation on screen. Try `puts CGI::unescapeHTML("...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually correct (the method).  It's returning what you want.

The `\` you are seeing before the double quotes are just artifacts of rendering a string with embedded double quotes, so that they're not interpreted as the end of the string.